# error 1193: unknown system variable (trigger)

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1193

I created a new column named garagem_coberta in my table. I can´t create the trigger because mysql says: unknown system variable 'garagem_coberta'.  Can someone help me?

```
delimiter //
create trigger update_garagem_coberta
before update on apartamento
for each row 
begin
if OLD.tipo = 'cobertura' then
set garagem_coberta = 'sim'
where valor = new.valor
end if;
end ;
//delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_garagem_coberta
BEFORE UPDATE ON apartamento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.tipo = 'cobertura' THEN
        SET NEW.garagem_coberta = 'sim';
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

check out this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Official example from documentation

```sql
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
               SET NEW.amount = 0;
           ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
               SET NEW.amount = 100;
           END IF;
       END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_garagem_coberta
BEFORE UPDATE ON apartamento
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.garagem_coberta = CASE WHEN OLD.tipo = 'cobertura' 
                               THEN 'sim'
                               ELSE NEW.garagem_coberta
                               END;
```

This is single-statement form, it does not need in both DELIMITER reassigning and BEGIN-END block usage.